# SQL Select statements that returns differences in minutes from next date-time from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a user activity table. I want to see a difference between each process in minutes.
To be more specific here is a partial data from table.

```
Date                |TranType|   Prod          |    Loc
-----------------------------------------------------------
02/27/12 3:17:21 PM | PICK   | LIrishGreenXL   |     E01C015
02/27/12 3:18:18 PM | PICK   | LAntHeliconiaS  |     E01A126
02/27/12 3:19:00 PM | PICK   | LAntHeliconiaL  |     E01A128
02/27/12 3:19:07 PM | PICK   | LAntHeliconiaXL |     E01A129
```

I want to retrieve time difference in minutes, between first and second process, than second and third and ....
Thank you

Comment: oops. Sorry it didn't rendered as I thought.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This is quite easy to do with [modern SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) like window functions.

Comment: Can you just use a stored procedure?

Comment: I want query for SSRS, so anything will work will be grate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work in MS SQL, just change the field names to match yours:

```html
select a.ActionDate, datediff(minute,a.ActionDate,b.ActionDate) as DiffMin

(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActionDate) AS Row, ActionDate
from [dbo].[Attendance]) a

inner join 

(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActionDate) AS Row, ActionDate
from [dbo].[Attendance]) b

on a.Row +1  = b.Row
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: independently sub queries returning right values. it looks like everything is right but ... Let me play more around

Comment: Cool, just join the two with plus one to the first one, so it joins to the second one, like above.

Comment: Nice, great job Revaz!

Comment: there was missing WERE clause... hehe

Comment: I had one, but then removed it to make the sample shorter. PS: can you mark the answer, we both could use the points!

Comment: Requires 15 reputation. I'm new here. Ill be back to this post to mark the answer.